# How to store values on pivot table in Laravel | many to Many

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to store product_id and subcategory_id in the pivot table. Can you help me.

- Product has many categories
- the subcategory has many products

In the category model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'product_SubCategory','product_id','subcategory_id'); 
}
```

in product Model

```
public function subcategory()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class,'product_SubCategory','subcategory_id','product_id' );
}
```

in Create Product View,

```
        <form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

                <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name">Product Name
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
                        <input type="text" id="first-name" required="required" class="form-control"
                            name="pro_name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name"> Sub Category
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
                        
                        <div class="form-check">
                            @foreach ($subcategory as $item)
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]"
                                    value="{{$item->id}}" id="defaultCheck1">{{$item->name}}
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Add Product</button>
        </form>
```

in dd($request)

```
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:8 [▼
      "_token" => "3YxgjIZn5nTPzd09NtjNfR3ViooXYIY7OomdGKiR"
      "pro_name" => null
      "category" => "3"
      "subcategory" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Store in Controller,

```
$product = new Product();
$product->pro_name = $request->pro_name;
$product->save(); 

$subcategory= new subcategory();
$subcategory->subcategory = $request->subcategory;
$product->subcategory()->save($subcategory);

return redirect()->route('product.index');
```

Comment: Can you show your storage function as it is now? Then I think I can help you out(please edit it into the question)

Comment: I added it. but it is wrong sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your info, I would change the relationship into this([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)):

```
//Product model
public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class,'product_SubCategory','subcategory_id','product_id' )->withPivot('subcategory_id ', 'product_id ');
}
```

And change the save into this([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#saving-additional-data-on-a-pivot-table)):

```
//store controller
...
$product->subcategory()->save($subcategory, ['product_id' => $request->product_id, 'subcategory_id' => $request->subcategory_id]);
...
```

In bare essence: `->withPivot` exposes the fields to the relationship, and the array in the `save()` fills them. Pleas note there is also a `sync()` option([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)) if you need to do this kind of saving in bulk. This also uses an array of options to fill the pivot.